# Rails 3 routing : customize a resourceful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I've got some Documents (and a DocumentsController), which are sorted using limited, fixed set of categories. I'd want my routes to take into account these categories, so my urls would look like :

```
/documents/:category/:id
/documents/:category/new
/documents/:category/:id/edit
```

...and so on, which should allow me to access params[:category] in order to filter the results. Is there a simple way to achieve this, *that would still generate path helpers* ? Or im i wrong to do this that way ?

Comment: I believe you want the document with the given id belonging to a category correct?

Comment: that's right. i'm currently trying to use `resources :documents, :path => "documents/:category"`, seems to work... is it okay ?

Comment: You can change the :path variable to be anything you like. This isn't quite namespacing, since the category is specified after the document. This is more like a nested resource with a custom :path. Checkout out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing for more information on namespaces, and nested resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a path to a resource (as you mentioned):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :documents, :path => 'documents/:category'
```

This would give you the following routes:

```
/documents/:category
/documents/:category/new
/documents/:category/:id/edit
/documents/:category/:id
```

I am not sure in this case what purpose the category capturing will serve, since you can reference the document by its primary key. This key most likely does not repeat across categories.

Comment: you're right about the PK, but i want to be able to narrow the scope of accessible documents. And right as i write this, it makes me understand that my approach is probably not the good one. maybe should i have an action per category on my controller, because i only really need this to have many index-like actions with narrowed scopes. I could even generate these actions via metaprogramming... thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to customize paths in Rails 3.

`match '/documents/:id', to: 'documents#show', as: :document` would give you the path helper `document_path(:id)`. This will work even for an ID that's a string rather than a number, so extending this pattern to `/documents/:category/:id/edit` should be no problem.